# Connect to SOAP in C#

Tags: c#, php, soap

I'm new to C# and used to work with PHP.
In PHP I used this code to connect to a SOAP-service:

```
<?
$client = new SoapClient('soapurl.com/soap.php?wsdl');
$createBatch = $client->createBatch('username','password');
$newstring = $createBatch['ResString'];
echo $newstring;
?>
```

How to do this in C#? I've added the soap-url to the reference of the solution.
I have this code so far:

```
createBatch b1 = new createBatch("username", "password");
this.label1.Text = ResString;
```

But how to get the string in the label?

Answer (score 0):

How to add web service reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx(v=vs.100).aspx
How to call a web service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h0yh8f9(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Visual Studio for your c# development. After you added the service reference for the soap service, Visual Studio will create strongly type classes for you to access the soap service. If you open the reference.cs file under the ServiceRefernce folder, you can see the generated code. Inside the file, you will see various types that are generated for all the requests and responses as well as interfaces and a soap client class.

The code to access your soap service will look something like the following.

```
var (var client = new MyServiceSoapClient) {
    var response = client.createBatch('username', 'password');
    string newstring = response.ResString;
}
```